# Powershell script to update Active Directory attribute

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have limited exposure to Powershell so I need some help.

I have a CSV file with just the `SamAccounName`.  I would like to use powershell to import that file and update the `employeeID` attribute with the `sammaccountname` value.  The import is the easy part:

```
$users = Import-Csv c:\filename.csv
```

Using the file to update the employeeid attribute is what I need help with.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please edit your question so as to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, you have mentioned `SamAccounName` and `sammaccountname`. Are these actually different, or Is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some great documentation about this here so you can get a good idea about this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617215.aspx

With RSAT Running you need to Import the AD Cmdlet's `Import-Module ActiveDirectory`

Once this is done you are starting to head down the appropriate path, try working with the following:

```
Import-CSV $csvFile | forEach { Set-ADUser $_.SamAccountName -EmployeeID $_.SamAccountName -WhatIf }
```

This can go much further, have a look at the top link instead of copying and pasting this code as you don't want to make error on this. But there should be enough information here to get you up and running.

Note the '-WhatIf' in the above code means PoSh will tell you what will happen rather than making it happen.

Comment: Thanks much.  Exactly what I needed.